# Calling a web dosen't work in Xamarin.Forms Windows Project

Tags: xamarin.forms, asp.net-web-api2

i'm using  Xamarin.Forms to developpe a mobile application in the three plateformes(Android,iOS and windows). My protable calss library  project calls a web APIs. So, when i run the android project it works well i mean i get data from the internet, but when i run the windows project it dosen't work i mean the call to the web APIs dosen't work.

Here the code of the methode i'm using:

```
protected async Task<T> Get<T>(string url)
    {
        using (var client = GetClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
                var error = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TrackSeriesApiError>();
                var message = error != null ? error.Message : "";
                throw new TrackSeriesApiException(message, response.StatusCode);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                throw new TrackSeriesApiException("", false, ex);
            }
            catch (UnsupportedMediaTypeException ex)
            {
                throw new TrackSeriesApiException("", false, ex);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error or indication why it isn't working?

Comment: I get this message : Message = "Method 'SerializeToStreamAsync' in type 'System.Net.Http.ObjectContent' from assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation."

Comment: I have changed my code and  now it works.                                               var resultString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
Contacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(resultString);